# Lost phone and WhatsApp issue

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, lost-phone

I lost my phone and I have some contacts on WhatsApp which I don't have anywhere else.

Is there any way to get those contacts? I have already deactivated my SIM card.

Can I get the data back?

Comment: Just wondering . Why a minus 1 for the question. I lost my ANDROID phone. And i believe this is the right place to ask as this is a forum related to android questions only !

Comment: No brother, this is a forum to ask questions about Android Phones, not the Android **lost** phones! :) You can ask for help by the police authorities or you can try your luck with the Android Device Manager from their site http://www.android.com/devicemanager

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan If what you say were true, we wouldn't have a [tag:lost-phone] tag with 72 questions, many of them with useful answers about how you can safeguard data on lost phones. This question is a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to say, but there is no or alternate way for this.

> I had lost my phone and i was having some contacts on whatsapp which i dont have anywhere else.

This thing is a bit wrong, because Whatsapp would use your own phonebook to check which of your contacts have whatsapp. It won't let you add any user to your stock pile by just adding them as friends.

> Is there any way to reach to that contacts .

If there is a backup of the data on Google servers, then there might be an option. But I don't think that would work! So there is no way to get them back.

> I know this is not a technical question concerned with android

True, but actually this is a site for the Android questions. So you're in the correct place. To ask how to get data, but now about **how to get data from a lost phone.** Thats impossible.

#### Possible things that would help

Well these are not the helping materials, but just in case to remind you that, in the settings, did you check `backup my data`. If so, try signing in Google from other phone, it might give you some data.

**Not sure of this** but you said the contacts were no where else but on whatsapp, so try signing in to whatsapp again, maybe they still have those contacts for you!

Comment: I found nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp does not remember your Gmail contact information. WhatsApp simply adds contacts from the phonebook. If you get a new phone and sync your Gmail account, then you will have those old contacts same as you had in old phone. That is the reason. WhatsApp primary ID is your phone number alone, not any other info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go to https://www.google.com/contacts/ and see if your contacts are backed up there?

That's the only possible way to get data from a stolen device, by having your data synced somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Sign back into watsapp your contacts will be there.  I was surprised to find them there when I signed back in but using a new number. I had lost my phone. Im guessing watsapp recognises your gmail sign in so your sync contacts to your google and watsapp account will.automatically be available.